# NodeJS: Freeze dependences before testing and deployment? Check in node_modules?

Tags: deployment, node.js, dependencies

Suppose you have a NodeJS application.
A release could consists of multiple steps:

1. Automated and/or manual tests
2. Deployment
3. (if something goes wrong) Rollback to the last stable version

There are some  desirable requirements regarding the application's dependencies:

- When you have done your testing, you want to deploy *exactly* the version that you tested with, including all dependencies.
- The same goes for rollbacks: You want to restore not only your own code, but all external dependencies, too.

My question is about best practices to meet this goals.

**What is the recommended way to create a snapshot of all dependencies of your NodeJS application?**

Here are three options that I can think of:

1. In [this article](http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html), the author recommends to put the `node_modules` directory under source control. (Not for all modules, but only for modules that will be deployed.)
2. One alternative, which the same article describes as an anti-pattern, is to use explicit version locking. His argument seems reasonable: When you lock, for example, Express to a certain version, you still cannot control that one of its dependences hasn't introduced a subtile bug, later.
3. Just don't care and always use the most recent version of all external modules.

---

My thoughts so far (but I don't have much experience with NodeJS yet):

- 3) seems to be too reckless.
- I tend to 1), but I'm not sure where to put the `node_modules`. When you just check it along with your normal code, I fear that workflows like `npm link` to your local modules will no longer work. Additionally, there is always the problem of annoying merge conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [npm shrinkwrap](https://npmjs.org/doc/shrinkwrap.html) to implement option #2 and lock all of the child dependencies. From the doc:

> This command locks down the versions of a package's dependencies so
>   that you can control exactly which versions of each dependency will be
>   used when your package is installed. The "package.json" file is still
>   required if you want to use "npm install".

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that command. Here, they also recommend to use shrinkwrap: http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2012/07/29/are-node_modules-in-git-still-necessary-with-npm-shrinkwrap-2/ Checking in still has some advantages, but it is not strictly required.

Answer (score -1):

I do not understand your nead of a node_modules version control. I mean you can easily define which version the dependency should have:

```
{
    "name": "native-gpio",

    "version": "0.0.6",

    "description": "sysfs GPIO wrapper for node.js",

    "author": "Bodo Kaiser <i@bodokaiser.io>",

    "license": "MIT",

    "keywords": ["gpio", "addon"],

    "main": "lib/index.js",

    "gypfile": true,

    "scripts": {
        "test": "make test",
        "install": "make install"
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "node-gyp": "0.10.6"
    },

    "devDependencies": {
        "mocha": "1.12.0",
        "chai": "1.7.2"
    },

    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git://github.com/bodokaiser/node-native-gpio.git"
    },

    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/bodokaiser/node-native-gpio/issues"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what he called "explicit version locking" in the article. His argument against it was that even if you now know that you are getting `node-gyp` version 0.10.6, you cannot be sure that all its dependencies are the exact same. Libraries, in general, will always use the latest versions. `npm shrinkwrap` will produce a `packages.json` where all dependences are explicit and thus seems to avoid that problem.